# How to remove parenthesis from a csv export python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

So I have a school assignment to create a GUI which allows me to add students to a database which I have made. I figured out how to search for students but I am struggling with being able to add students. I am required to export this data to a CSV file. I have managed to export it but it comes with commas, speech marks and brackets, which I don't want. This is my code so far for the section that doesn't work:

```
def reveal(self):
    firstname = ("Forename: ", self.forename_entry.get())
    lastname = ("Surname: ", self.surname_entry.get())
    gender_ = ("Gender: ", self.gender_entry.get())
    birthdate = ("DOB: ", self.DOB_entry.get())
    Student_ID = ("Student ID Number: ", self.studentID_entry.get())
    home = ("Address: ", self.address_entry.get())
    phone = ("Home phone number: ", self.homephone_entry.get())
    group = ("Tutor Group: ", self.tutorgroup_entry.get())
    school_email = ("School Email", self.sch_email_entry.get())

    with open("StudentIDs.csv", "a") as f:
        w = csv.writer(f, quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        writeit = (['\n', firstname, '\n', lastname, '\n', gender_, '\n', birthdate, '\n', Student_ID, '\n', home, '\n', phone, '\n', group, '\n', school_email])
        w.writerow(writeit)
        self.invalidtext.configure(text = "Student added")
```

Comment: `(thing, other_thing)` is not string concatenation; you may have gotten confused by how `print(thing, other_thing)` prints two things as if they were joined by a space. String concatenation is `+` (though you do need to make sure you have strings).

Comment: user2357112 By replacing the ',' with '+' I instead get an error:        TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly

Comment: May I see the Output of `writeit`, [Edit] your Question accordingly. **Note**: Use @ in front of Username to make sure your Comment reach the User!

Comment: @stovfl Oh sorry. I'm new to this I don't ask many questions. But yeh the output looks something like this:                                                                 "('Forename: ', 'TEST15')","
","('Surname: ', 'TEST15')","
","('Gender: ', 'TEST15')","
","('DOB: ', 'TEST15')","
","('Student ID Number: ', 'TEST15')","
","('Address: ', 'TEST15')","
","('Home phone number: ', 'TEST15')","
","('Tutor Group: ', 'TEST15')","
","('School Email', 'TEST15')"

Answer (score 0):

Change  from `tuple` to `dict`:

> [class csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames, restval=”, extrasaction=’raise’, dialect=’excel’, *args, **kwds)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)
>   Create an object which operates like a regular writer but maps dictionaries onto output rows.
>   The fieldnames parameter is a sequence of keys that identify the order in which values in the dictionary passed to the writerow() method are written to file f.

```
record ={}
record["Forename"] = self.forename_entry.get()
record["Surname"] = self.surname_entry.get()
... an so on

with open("StudentIDs.csv", "a") as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=list(record.keys()))
    if firstRow:
        w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(record)
```